# Could not write data to a tkinter table from the other class

Tags: python, tkinter, barcode-scanner

I am trying to add my GUI and get data from the  simple scanner demo application in python. This scanner demo application handles various events like scan event, scanner_connected, scanner_disconnected etc.

Initially I'm calling the GUI class in the demo application to initiate the GUI.
When the scan event raises , I take the data and pass the data to a Bridge class.
After that I call a GUI function called write_data which is responsible to print the data to a table.
This write_table function calls the Bridge class to get the updated scan data

```py
#app_example.py 
import myGUI
class Bridge:  # a class to store the data from the scan_event
    var1 = "data"

    def __init__(self):
        # does
        nothing

    def update_data(self, user_info):
        global var1
        var1 = user_info

    def get_data(self):
        global var1
        return var1

# function from the APi to get the scan data
def on_scan(client: Client, event: ScanEvent) -> None:
    user_name = response_text["user"]
    b = Bridge()  
    b.update_data(user_name) # saving the scan data to a function from Bridge class
    mygui = mainGUI()
    mygui.write_table()  # calling the GUI  function to write data to a table

# function from the APi
def app_example():     
handler = GatewayMessageHandler(
    on_scanner_connected=on_connected,
    on_scanner_disconnected=on_disconnected,
    on_scan=on_scan,
    on_error=on_error,
    on_button_pressed=on_button_pressed_event
)
logger.info('application started, press Ctrl-C to exit')

mygui = mainGUI()
mygui.build_gui()  # calling the GUI 

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1000)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    gateway.stop()


# myGUI.py 


class mainGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        # does
        nothing

    def build_gui(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Barcode Scanner 1.0")

        frame_COMinf = tk.Frame(window)
        frame_COMinf.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        # initating a thread to the function write_table
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.write_table)
        self.thread.start()

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use("clam")
        style.element_create("Custom.Treeheading.border", "from", "default")
        style.layout("Custom.Treeview.Heading", [
            ("Custom.Treeheading.cell", {'sticky': 'nswe'}),
            ("Custom.Treeheading.border", {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                ("Custom.Treeheading.padding", {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                    ("Custom.Treeheading.image", {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}),
                    ("Custom.Treeheading.text", {'sticky': 'we'})
                ]})
            ]}),
        ])

        frame = tk.Frame(window)
        style.theme_use("clam")
        frame.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), height=20, show="headings", 
                     style="Custom.Treeview")
        self.tree.pack(side='left')

        style.configure("Custom.Treeview.Heading",
                    background="blue", foreground="white", relief="flat")
        style.map("Custom.Treeview.Heading",
              relief=[('active', 'groove'), ('pressed', 'sunken')])

        self.tree.heading(1, text="Ser.No")
        self.tree.heading(2, text="user")

        self.tree.column(1, width=50, anchor='center')
        self.tree.column(2, width=100, anchor='center')

        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.scroll.pack(side='right', fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        window.mainloop()

    def write_table(self):
        # this function calls the Bridge class and get the scan data
        global serNo
        bridge = Bridge() 
        user_data = bridge.get_data()
        data = [[serNo, user_data]]
        for val in data:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(val[0], val[1]), tags=('gr',))
            serNo += 1
            self.tree.tag_configure('gr', background='green')
```

The error I get is

```
self.tree.insert('', 'end', values = (val[0], val[1]), tags=('gr',))
   AttributeError: 'mainGUI' object has no attribute 'tree'
```

I do not have much knowledge in object-oriented programming using python. Could someone help how to write the data for this table?

Comment: Those comment `/* ... */` and `// ...` are not valid Python syntax.

Comment: Sorry for my C style comments. I have called build_gui once in the function app_example to initate the GUI. Thereafter, I need to just add the data to the GUI.  If I call the build_gui for example in the write_table function, It opens again a new GUI window.

Comment: Better post the full traceback.  Inside `on_scan()`, you forgot to call `mygui.build_gui()` before calling `mygui.write_table()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I have tried that. The data is coming to the table. The problem is I see a new window for every scan event. I double checked, I did not missed any code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the class Singleton solved the issue.

```
class mainGUI:

    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(mainGUI, cls).__new__(
                            cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):

        self.check = False

    def build_gui(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        global x,y
        x = window.winfo_x()
        y = window.winfo_y()
        #rest of the code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While it is actually a good comment and the person who asked think it's the correct solution, you may want to improve your answer a bit more. It would be much nicer if you can add: 
1. More explanations of why your solution differ from the solution mentioned in the question.
2. More inline documentation on which lines of code that actually impact the process

Answer (score 0):

The write_data function is not indented and is not a method of the class mainGUI. (This was fixed)

You try to access the self.tree variable before it is initialized.

The line where you call self.tree:

```
self.thread = Thread(target=self.write_table)
```

And you are initializing it further down:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), height=20, show="headings", 
                 style="Custom.Treeview")
```

A default self.tree in __ init__() would help you.

If you cannot set it in the init method of the class then maybe something like this can help:

```
for val in data:
    try:
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=(val[0], val[1]), tags=('gr',))
    except AttributeError:  # And do the initialization here. Pretty ugly though.
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), height=20, show="headings", style="Custom.Treeview")
        # ... do all other stuff with the Treeview widget.
    # ...
    # do as normal
```

But I don't know where exactly you need this initialized in the first place. This would be the absolute latest you need to initialize it.

Comment: This code is actually edited to show here.  Actually it is indented. I will correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You started a thread to run `write_data()` inside `build_gui()` before creating `self.tree`:

```
class mainGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        # does nothing
        pass

    def build_gui(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Barcode Scanner 1.0")

        frame_COMinf = tk.Frame(window)
        frame_COMinf.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        # initating a thread to the function write_table
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.write_table)
        self.thread.start()
        ### the above code will execute `write_table()` before `self.tree` is created
        
        ...

        frame = tk.Frame(window)
        style.theme_use("clam")
        frame.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), height=20, show="headings",
                     style="Custom.Treeview")
        self.tree.pack(side='left')

        ...

        window.mainloop()
```

So better create and start the thread before `window.mainloop()`:

```py
class mainGUI:
    ...

    def build_gui(self):
        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Barcode Scanner 1.0")

        frame_COMinf = tk.Frame(window)
        frame_COMinf.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
        ...

        frame = tk.Frame(window)
        style.theme_use("clam")
        frame.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), height=20, show="headings",
                     style="Custom.Treeview")
        self.tree.pack(side='left')

        ...

        # initating a thread to the function write_table
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.write_table)
        self.thread.start()

        window.mainloop()
```

---

Another suspect cause:

```py
# function from the APi to get the scan data
def on_scan(client: Client, event: ScanEvent) -> None:
    user_name = response_text["user"]
    b = Bridge()  
    b.update_data(user_name) # saving the scan data to a function from Bridge class
    mygui = mainGUI()
    ### as mygui.build_gui() is not called
    ### below line will raise the error
    mygui.write_table()  # calling the GUI  function to write data to a table
```

Comment: I tried it now. I still see the same error

Comment: @Ghani That's why I said in my comment in your question: *Better post the full traceback* because it has more useful information.  And most important is provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Trust me all the other code is not related to the GUI stuff. I have tried your suggestion by adding mygui.build_gui()  I get the below error self.tk.call(self._name, "element", "create", elementname, etype,
_tkinter.TclError: Duplicate element Custom.Treeheading.border

Comment: @Ghani We don't need the other part of your application, we just want a *runable example* that can reproduce the issue.  Your posted code cannot be executed due to some missing parts, for example `Client`, `ScanEvent`, etc and so how can we reproduce the issue.  We can just guess what the cause of the issue.

Comment: If I delete the GUI initalization in the function app_example and keep  `mygui.build_gui()` in the `on_scan` function as you mentioned, I see data entering in to the table once. For the next scan I see an error: `res = self.tk.call(self._w, "insert", parent, index, *opts)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame2.!treeview"`